# How do I cut and serve my ribs?

Tags: cutting, ribs

I slow-cooked spare ribs on my grill yesterday:

[image]

I'm not sure if that picture does it justice, but they were very tasty.

The problem I had was cutting and serving them to my family.  Is there a particular knife I should use to cut these ribs?

Also, is there a particular way I should cut them?  I'm trying to reduce the mess.

Comment: You're trying to avoid making a mess with ribs? That's like trying to avoid salt with pickles, or awkwardness with in-laws, or food safety on SeasonedAdvice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd personally go with a standard carving set: Very sharp non serrated long carving knife and a carving fork to help hold the meat steady without getting in-there with your hands.

Assuming you're right handed I'd start on the right with the with the ribs running up away from you, maybe slightly pointing to the left. Then cut along the bone, close to the bone so all the meat is on one side the finished cut. You should be able to get your fork one rib along the rack from where you're cutting but work out what feels best

Answer (score 3):

I think the most important thing is to make sure your knife is sharp. I would also make sure you let the ribs rest for 10 minutes or so. Then, you should be able to stand them on edge, with the tips up in the air and cut down cleanly between the bones. If your ribs are are pulling away from the bone too much for this, then you can lay them flat with the bone towards the board and then cut them.

Comment: serrated knife?